# Question about SQL clause

Tags: sql

I have a database with names like this:

```
Maria Garcia Garralon 
Jose Maria Perez Gutierrez
```

I have a filter also to search the names. Imagine the user write in the filter

> maria garralon

(the first and the last words)

In that case, is there any SQL clause that finds the record "Maria Garcia Garralon" ?

Regards

Javi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could split your search terms and perform multiplie LIKE clauses. Such as:

```
WHERE
    Field LIKE '%maria%'
AND
    Field LIKE '%garralon%'
```

Alternatively, if you can be sure of the order of the search terms ans spaces between them then you could always do something like this.

```
WHERE
    Field LIKE REPLACE('maria garralon', ' ', '%')
```

Comment: When doing this kind of query, you may want to anchor the beginning/end of each word with spaces, for example `lower(' '||field||' ') LIKE '% maria %'`. Otherwise you may find surprising "matches" like "Fred Martin" matching "Winifred Martinez".

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use a hideous non-scalable query segment along the lines of:

```
where upper(name) like 'MARIA % GARRALON'
```

or you can do it the right way :-)

Introduce another column like `first_and_last_name` and use an insert/update trigger to populate it with the correct value `maria garralon`. Then index that column and your queries will be the blindingly fast:

```
where first_and_last_name = 'maria garralon'
```

That moves the cost of calculation to the insert/update where it belongs, rather than the select where the cost is incurred unnecessarily. The data only changes on insert/update so that's the *only* time you should need to incur that cost.

If your needs are more complicated than a simple first and last name, you can populate other tables in your triggers.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you'd need to compare twice:

(pseudo syntax)
WHERE name LIKE '%Maria%'
AND name LIKE '%Garralon%'

Answer (score 0):

Would something like:

```
select * from <TABLE>
 where <FIELD> like '%'+REPLACE(<NAME>,' ',' % ')+'%'
```